# AutoMapper: Migrar de la versión 4.1.1 a la 5.2.0

Tags: c#, automapper

Estoy usando la versión 4.1.1 de AutoMapper en este servicio y me gustaría actualizar a la versión 5.2.0 de AutoMapper. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

```
public class ViewModelMapperService
{
private ConfigurationStore _configuration;
private MappingEngine _engine;

public ViewModelMapperService()
{
    this._configuration = new ConfigurationStore(new TypeMapFactory(), MapperRegistry.Mappers);
    this._engine = new MappingEngine(_configuration);
}

public void Map<TSource, TTarget>(TSource source, TTarget target)
{
    this.CreateMap<TSource, TTarget>();
    this._engine.Map(source, target);
}

public TTarget Map<TSource, TTarget>(TSource source)
{
    this.CreateMap<TSource, TTarget>();
    return this._engine.Map<TSource, TTarget>(source);
}

public void MapToModel<TSource, TTarget>(TSource source, TTarget target) where TTarget : IBaseObject
{
    this.CreateVmToModelMap<TSource, TTarget>();
    this._engine.Map(source, target);
}

public void MapToViewModel<TSource, TTarget>(TSource source, TTarget target) where TTarget : IViewModel
{
    this.CreateModelToVmMap<TSource, TTarget>();
    this._engine.Map(source, target);
}

private void CreateMap<TSource, TTarget>()
{
    this._configuration.CreateMap<TSource, TTarget>();
}

private void CreateModelToVmMap<TSource, TTarget>() where TTarget : IViewModel
{
    this._configuration.CreateMap<TSource, TTarget>().ForMember(t => t.IsDirty, opt => opt.Ignore());
}

private void CreateVmToModelMap<TSource, TTarget>() where TTarget : IBaseObject
{
    this._configuration.CreateMap<TSource, TTarget>().ForMember(t => t.IsDirty, opt => opt.Ignore());
}
}
```

Comment: Hola @davidop , este es un foro en Castellano/Español, por favor reformula tu pregunta para que te podamos ayudar, if you wish to ask in english, this is the place http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: pero que es esa clase que has publicado el codigo? es como si hubieras realizado uan abstraccion con metodo para maprear, no le veo mucho sentido. Con la nueva version de automaper tiene Profile que puede definir. Leiste algo de la documentacion de la nueva version?

Comment: Es código heredado que me encontré en la versión 1.1.0.118 y he conseguido actualizar hasta las 4.1.1. Mi idea es llevarlo hasta las 5.2.0 pero me esta resultado imposible.